# How to grab only selected components image while capturing the JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

JPanel with 3 JButton and I need only two of them to be captured...

```
public static void grabScreenShot(JPanel panel) {
    BufferedImage image = (BufferedImage) panel.createImage(
            panel.getSize().width, panel.getSize().height);
    panel.paint(image.getGraphics());
    File file = null;
    file = new File("Customers");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }

    try {
        file = new File("Customers" + File.separator
                + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        System.out.println("Image was created");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Had trouble writing the image.");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

How to avoid unnecessary components to be captured.?

Comment: Many options here, some hacky and some clean, some invasive and some not. Overriding the `paintComponent` of the button (as proposed in one answer) might be an option, but makes the logic for hiding the button very prominent (considering that this capturing is most likely a very special case). How about just painting a rectangle (with the panel background color) at the place where the button was? Something like `g.setColor(panel.getBackground()); ((Graphics2D)g).fill(button.getBounds());` should do it..

Comment: Nope actually I forgot that I am not using button but I am using the `Core.ellipse(mRgba, center1, size, 0, 0, 360, new Scalar(255, 0,255), 1, 8, 0);` To draw the ellipse from the OpenCV library. Sorry for that...

Comment: It should still be possible to either paint something over the ellipse (just do `g.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(...));`, or to omit the ellipse from being painted (with `g.setClip(...)`), as StanislavL suggested

Comment: If the question is answered, you should either say how you did it (so that a comment may be turned into an answer), or write an answer to your own question.

Comment: Ohk I will do it shortly...

Comment: I tried using the size.height=0 and size.width=0 of the ellipse but there is one point also becomes drawn while capturing but I need to make it clear and clean any idea ?

Comment: (EDIT: You did not say which approach you are using now) Individual pixels being filled or not may depend on the definition of insideness in OpenCV (for Swing, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html#def_insideness ). You could try `g.fill(ellipse)` **AND** `g.draw(ellipse)`. Otherwise, more code might help (preferably as http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, although I can imagine that it may be difficult to create one when libs like OpenCL are involved...)

Comment: My mistake dear @Marco13 but here I am using OpenCV API also to draw the ellipse on screen where faces are detected but i don't want to show the ellipse in Image but it should be drawn on screen...

Comment: Maybe you should edit yout quesiton with this (more detailed) information. For me, it sounds like an additional infrastructure for this *might* be appropriate: You could use a flag (like StanislavL proposed), but this flag is not built into an overridden method, but into the respective class that is actually *responsible* for painting (or not painting) the ellipse by calling `Core.ellipse(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to override `paintComponent()` of the buttons and introduce a flag needPaint. The flag is true by default.

```
if (needPaint) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
}
```

In your grabScreenShot() set the flag to false for the button to be hidden and reset it back after `panel.paint(image.getGraphics());` call

Comment: Actually I am using the OpenCV and I just need to disappear the ellipse `Core.ellipse(mRgba, center, size, 0, 0, 360, new Scalar(255, 0,255), 1, 8, 0);` and this is not possible to use the `paintComponent()` method.

Comment: If you have bounds of the button you can define Area for clip shape where the bounds are excluded. Just set the clip shape to your Graphics instance.

Comment: @StanislavL programatically by stop repainting - setIgnoreRepaint, but I don't know (if is there, and how is) the impact to paintChildren

Comment: @mKorbel Guess the buttons jut don't have children at all.

Comment: Wo wo wo Sorry everybody `Core.ellipse(mRgba, center, size, 0, 0, 360,new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 1, 8, 0);` is not any Swing component it comes from the `org.opencv.core.Core;` package I don't know how to prevent it to drawing it on screen ?

Comment: By setting desired clip Shape

Comment: +1 for your quick response and perfect response...thanks and sorry to be late @StanislavL now you can too select my question as a favorite and up vote it too.